# Github REST API: list collaborators

Tags: github, postman, github-api, github-api-v3

I need to retrieve a list of people we're paying the Github license for. So it includes:

- members
- outside collaborators
- pending invitations

While it's rather easy to read the members, I have no idea what is the right way to get the list of outside collaborators. Sure, there is an endpoint /repos/{owner}/{repo}/collaborators but I'd need to go through hundreds/thousands of repos and check for collaborators, one by one. Is there a better way to get the list of people we're paying for?
I found nothing in billing API.

Thank you

Comment: There is [/orgs/{org}/outside_collaborators](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/orgs/outside-collaborators?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-outside-collaborators-for-an-organization) and [/orgs/{org}/invitations](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/orgs/members?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-pending-organization-invitations) now, but I still can’t find the list of pending outside collaborators.

Answer (score -1):

If you're on Enterprise, you can see those stats in the portal in a single click:

[image]

For free organisations and teams, you can see the membership status here:

```
https://github.com/orgs/{orgname}/people
```

[image]

Comment: I need to retrieve the information via REST API, and we're not on enterprise plan.